# Filtering app engine data from datastore dynamically

Tags: python, google-app-engine

My app-engine data model is defined as:

```
class Event(db.Model):
    title = db.LinkProperty();
    refresh_interval = db.IntegerProperty(); 

class EventSchedule(db.Model):
    event = db.ReferenceProperty(Event)     # referencing the event
    refresh_date = db.DateTimeProperty();   # date & time of last successful refresh
```

I'd like to fetch all EventSchedule items based on the criteria of:

```
event_schedule.refresh_date + event.refresh_interval >= now
```

In SQL-land, it would look something like:
    DATE_ADD(event_schedule.refresh_date, event.refreshInterval) >= now()

Is this kind of join operation feasible with the data store?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This join operation is not possible with the GAE data store, and is highly inefficient on normal SQL databases as well (since it requires a scan of the entire event_schedule table).

You should instead store a `next_refresh` `DateTimeProperty` in your `EventSchedule` entities, initialized to be `refresh_date + refresh_interval` when the entity is created, and simply test for `next_refresh >= now`.

Comment: Thanks - I didn't think to reverse the logic there.